# PEP 8 continuation line under-indented for visual indent for Vim?

Tags: python, vim, pep8

I am trying to configure vim to indent in accordance with pep8 e128.

```
return redirect(url_for('list_feedbacks_for_profile',
                        profile_id=feedback.key().id_or_name()))
```

What should I put in my .vimrc to indent profile_id to immediately below the ' character?

Answer (score 1):

There are some good pointers on the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) but I think to do what you want you may want to try [vim-python-pep8-indent](https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent) project. While I haven't used it myself it seems to be focused on this very topic.